# Convert $\rm Lux$ to $\rm W/m^2$

Tags: visible-light, si-units, solar-cells, light-emitting-diodes, intensity

I use four LED matrix (UV, green, red, blue) to irradiate a solar panel with an area of ***S*** at a distance. The matrix is located at a distance ***l*** from the solar panel. I want to plot the volt-ampere characteristics of a solar panel, but usually on such graphs they sign the density of incident radiation in watts per square meter. I only have a luxmeter with which I can measure the illumination of the solar panel. Can you tell me if I can get the incident flux density from the illumination and how do I do it?  If suddenly you conducted a similar experience, share what efficiency factor you got?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't get what you want just from Lux ratings.  Lux, and candela, and lumens, measure how strongly the human retina responds to the light source.  If your sources were extremely narrowband, then you could look up the retinal response efficiency to the specific wavelength and perhaps thus back-calculate the source's output in watts/sr.

If you can find spectral output curves for your LEDs then you can convolve those curves with the spectral quantum efficiency of the solar panels to determine the useable output power.   I suspect the "watts per square meter" data you have for solar panels is based on the spectral irradiance curve for sunlight at the Earth's surface.

Comment: OK. And how to find the power of radiation incident on the solar panel? This is necessary to evaluate the efficiency of the solar panel.